# FOP, xsl-fo: disable line break

Tags: pdf-generation, line-breaks, xsl-fo, apache-fop

With xsl-fo, I want to generate a pdf-file. 
The text for the pdf-file is a simple ongoing plain-text without any line-breaks in it. When I generate the pdf, there are line-breaks in the pdf, so after copying the text into Notepad, there are those line breaks, too.

What I want is, that in the pdf, there are those line-breaks, but not in the copied text in Notepad.

---

**Example**:
*original text:*

```
this is a xsl-fo generated text
```

*text in pdf:*

```
this is a xsl-fo
generated text
```

*text by copy-paste out of the pdf:*

```
this is a xsl-fo generated text
```

---

Here is the snippet, I use for the generation (it is from our CMS):

```
<fo:block margin-bottom="12pt" font-size="11pt">$CMS_VALUE(#content)$</fo:block>
```

---

I played around with

```
keep-together.within-column="always"
```

and

```
wrap-option="wrap"
```

and

```
linefeed-treatment="treat-as-space"
```

But nothing seems to work. Is it even possible to realize something like this?

Hope you can help me.

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want is, that in the pdf, there are those line-breaks,

FOP is responsible for breaking the text into lines and, as you say, it is doing its job.

> but not
>   in the copied text in Notepad.

This has nothing to do with FOP.

The behaviour of copy-and-paste from a pdf to notepad depends on the pdf reader and the notepad application, not on the application that created the pdf.

On Mac Os, for example, copying text from the preview application (the one that opens pdf files) to a text editor concatenates the lines belonging to the same paragraph (i.e. the behaviour you desire).